# iOS Kiosk App - In-App Email - Clear past / autocomplete email addresses

Tags: ios, email, caching, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, in-app

I am using the iOS MFMailComposeView method of sending emails - its all working fine, except that as a Kiosk app, I don't want each new user to see the auto complete list of previous email addresses that this app / iPad has used.

Is there a programmatical way to clear that cache after each email has been sent?

I can't see from the Dev docs, but I'm sure I'm not the only one that's butted up against this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had confirmation from Apple that there is no way to do this at all without a complete reset/wipe of the iPad between 'events'.

I logged  Bug ID# 10328043   and in the reply was told that they already knew about this 'problem' as the original bug ID # is 5389647

If anyone else would like to help raise this as an issue requiring a sooner rather than never solution, please bug it and reference the two above ID's.

Thanks